# three spatial dimension density plotting in R

Tags: r, plot, voxel

I have a data set
x and y are horizontal spatial coordinates, z is the vertical spatial coordinate.
The data set is individual entry:

x1,y1,z1,obsevervation_Data1

x2,y2,z2,obsevervation_Data2

etc....

I want to create a plot that fills each voxel in a three dimensional plot with a color according to the number of points in that voxel. This will ignore the observation_Data, I just want to count the number of observations in each 3-d cell and plot the color of that cell accordingly. Colors can be binned (i.e. 0 clear, 1-10obs green, 10-50 observations yellow>50 observations red).

Is there a package that does anything like this or am I going to have to craft it by hand?

I have tried looking at vignettes for the libraries scatterplot3d , lattice, rgl and plot3D but I haven't come across any way to do this or even anyone who has done anything similar.

Comment: You can create a wide range of 3D plots in R using the {rayshader} and/or {rayrender} packages - they might be worth a look?

Comment: Yeah, I have seen rayshader too. Upon further reflection this just may not be possible. I may have to bin one of the dimensions and create a series of plots, one for each bin.